# Calculate profit or defecit of a hazard game

Tags: probability, expected-value

Hi i have a hazard game that costs $\$5$ for entry. When i pay for the game and spin a wheel i have:

$40\%$ chance to get $\$2$

$30\%$ to get $\$4$

$20\%$ to get $\$15$

$9,9\%$ to get $\$30$

$0,1\%$ to get $\$200$

I am looking for general formula how to calculate if this game be profitable or not? And about how much?
For example final answer could be game will be profitable and after millions of spins I get back $\$5.13$ average per spin.

Its for my computer game, I am a programmer that is dumb in math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is multiply each amount by the probability of getting that amount, and add them up. So you get $0.4\times 2+0.3\times 4+\cdots$.

You should find that the game is very profitable.